# Alternative keyboard map for diacritics and other symbols for US layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Over one year ago I found an alternative keyboard layout/keymap for US keyboards, to help type accents, umlauts, and other diacritics, as well as Greek letters, mathematical symbols, subscripts and superscripts, etc.

It looked super handy, but I failed to bookmark it so now I have no idea what it was called. I remember it was written by a German (or French?) speaker. I routinely write in multiple languages + mathematics, so this could really be a productivity booster.

Comment: “US International” layout might be it.  I haven’t tried it myself.  I don’t know who the original author of that was (if there was one).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean the neo layout? It has 6 layers:

- layer 1 is for letters + numbers
- layer 2 is for shifted letters + money symbols
- layer 3 is for special chars like brackets, hash etc. (good for programmers)
- layer 4 is for arrow keys and numpad
- layer 5 and 6 are for greek letters and mathematical symbols etc.

https://neo-layout.org/